# Reservations as Post

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I am creating a multi-user, multi-product, multi-product-category reservations engine proof of concept. As I need to build it really fast I am using Wordpress's custom post types to manage a lot of the data.

I have reached a cross roads as I have modelled individual reservations as a post type, however, as the ones who will be making said reservations may not be registered and/or will be users with the subscriber role. Is it possible for them to still create a reservations post type?

Comment: Sure. I'd say that's readily possible. Are you doing this all custom or are you existing using plugins? (e.g. Gravity Forms has some nice add-ons that sound like they'd do a lot of what you've described).

Answer (score 0):

Read about roles and capabilities on codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: While roles and capabilities might be related to a solution, merely pointing to the Codex page for those topics isn't a complete answer. Once you get a little bit of rep you can post this kind of thing  as a comment.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I know, I would've written it in a comment, but couldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 'reservations' custom post type:

```
function my_add_capabilities() {
    $role_obj = get_role('subscriber');
    $role_obj->add_cap('edit_reservations');
    $role_obj->add_cap('publish_reservations');
    $role_obj->add_cap('delete_reservations');
}
```

As capabilities are stored in database, hook this function to the theme activation hook such as `switch_theme` to add capabilities only when theme is switched. You'll need to switch the theme to any other and back to yours in admin panel.

```
add_action('switch_theme', 'my_add_capabilities');
```

[Function Reference/add_cap](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap).

If you want to remove capabilities, use `remove_cap` function in likely manner. You need to run it once.

```
function my_remove_capabilities() {
    $role = get_role('subscriber');
    $role_obj->remove_cap('edit_reservations');
    $role_obj->remove_cap('publish_reservations');
    $role_obj->remove_cap('delete_reservations');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_remove_capabilities');
```

[Function Reference/remove cap](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap)